# Updating the value in dictionary when the values is in tuple with nested dictionary?

Tags: python

```
Dict_1 = {}
Dict_1['Sample_Data'] =  [(None, None, None)]

Dict_2 =  {}
Dict_2['detail'] = {'status1' : 0, 'status2' : 0}

File = 'abc.txt'
File_time = '10282020'

Dict_1['Sample_Data'].insert(0,(File, File_time, Dict_2))
```

Now, Dict_1 will be

```
{'Sample_Data' : ('abc.txt',10282020,{'details' : {'status1' : 0, 'status2' : 0}), (None, None, None)}
```

Likewise, if I insert more data in Dict_1 then Dict_1 will be -

```
{'Sample_Data' : ('file2.txt', '10292020',{'details' : {'status4' : 1, 'status5' : 1}}),('abc.txt','10282020',{'details' : {'status1' : 0, 'status2' : 0}}), (None, None, None)}
```

How can I update the values of status 4 and status 5 to 0 for file2.txt in Dict_1?

Comment: i suggest you to change the data type in DICT_1 to python class object and the do operation on those class object that would be more easy to handle and process

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values and update them (if you know the paths):

```
Dict_1['Sample_Data'][0][2]['details']['status4'] = 0
Dict_1['Sample_Data'][0][2]['details']['status5'] = 0

print(Dict_1)
```

Output:

```
{'Sample_Data': [('file2.txt', '10292020', {'details': {'status4': 0, 'status5': 0}}), ('abc.txt', '10282020', {'details': {'status1': 0, 'status2': 0}}), (None, None, None)]}
```

If you don't know the paths:

```
for f in Dict_1['Sample_Data']:
  if f[0] == 'file2.txt':
    f[2]['details']['status4'] = 0
    f[2]['details']['status5'] = 0
    break

print(Dict_1)
```

Output:

```
{'Sample_Data': [('file2.txt', '10292020', {'details': {'status4': 0, 'status5': 0}}), ('abc.txt', '10282020', {'details': {'status1': 0, 'status2': 0}}), (None, None, None)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer:

```
Dict_1['Sample_Data'][0][2]['detail']['status4'] = 0
Dict_1['Sample_Data'][0][2]['detail']['status5'] = 0
```

Tangentially related:

Your test data uses tuples to store None data. Unlike lists, tuples are immutable meaning they can't be changed.
Tuples in Python use round brackets "()", lists use square "[]".
The reason for this is simply performance, tuples are more efficient for read-only data.

Comment: You can't assign to tuples by indexing, but you can modify the objects inside, for instance, if `t = ([1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4])`, you can do `t[1].sort() ; print(t)`, and it would be `([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])`.

Comment: True, but the question gives an empty tuple = (None, None, None).

Comment: That could be some sort of end-of-list or no-file indication or something, but whatever it is, the question asks about updating a tuple with objects inside, which you can do.

Comment: If that's the case it's inclusion is unnecessary.  Updated answer to be more direct anyway. Their code wouldn't run due to typos but I did fix and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Although a tuple is immutable, it contains references to objects like lists and dictionaries and those objects can be changed. However, the references themselves can't be changed. So its possible to update you dictionary within the tuple.

Try this:

```
tup = Dict_1['Sample_Data'][0]
tup[-1]['details']['status4'] = 2 #new value
tup[-1]['details']['status5'] = 3 #new value
```

Comment: This is one way to do it, but you don't have to convert the tuples to lists if you are only modifying the objects inside, rather than assigning new values to them.